# What causes the initial index.html file to disappear when href'ing from another html file

Tags: html, css, node.js, express

I am trying to create a web portfolio using html, css, node and particlesJS.
Here is a quick reference to my index.js file where in here I've coded expresss to include the static files(style.css, images,...etc) inside of the folder named static so they're utilized when I run the local server with nodemon. The server runs and loads the initial index.html file. When I click to go to the about me page, that works too. My problem is clicking back to the "Me" page. When I set href="../index.html" , I get the error  "Cannot GET /index.html".
I have tried including all the files including index.html in the same folder and making a reference to that in the index.JS file. No avail.

```
// create an express app
const express = require("express")
const app = express()

// use the express-static middleware
app.use(express.static("public"))
app.use("/static", express.static('./static/'));
// define the first route
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
    
})

// start the server listening for requests
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000,
    () => console.log("Server is running... on localhost:3000"));

Here's another reference to how my directory is setup [Directory][https://imgur.com/JaGaxkd]

This is the about me html file from which I want to navigate back to the first index.html
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Meet Me</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">

<body>
    
    <div id="particles-js" class="topnav">
        <head>About</head>
        <H3>About ME</H3>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="../index.html">Me</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="./particles.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I believe I have the paths right but I think I am missing something I'm just not sure what it is . I would appreciate any help on this. Much thanks in advance

Comment: You could set `href="/"` and that should work.  The line `app.get("/", ` tells the server how to respond to `/`, not `/index.html`.

Comment: It worked!  Many thanks Kind stranger. I appreciate yoru help a lot.